# Как отключить часть кода в скрипте unity c#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Можно ли отключить метод/функцию в скрипте ,черз изменение значения поля в инспекторе (до запуска приложения ,разумеется).И если можно ,то как это сделать?

PS пытался так ↓,но не получилось(

```
    public static bool isTriggerEnter;

#if isTriggerEnter
    private Collider OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
       return collider;
    }
#endif
```

Также использовал [Conditional()],но не помогло.

Comment: Заведите bool поле. Допишите в начало метода `if (имяПеременной) return null;`

Comment: Директивы `#if` для компилятора, они не существуют во премя выполнения.

Comment: Мне нужно ,что бы сама unity не могла вызывать OnTriggerEnter, я хочу сделать удобный способ выбора/фильтрации в инспекторе ,для того ,что бы на моих 1000 объектах вызывалась только одна из 3 проверок OnTriggerEnter/OnTriggerExit/OnTriggerStay . Возможно это невозможно и мне придётся просто создать 3 скрипта ...

Comment: Вас спасет наследование. ООП же знаете. Создайте базовый класс, унаследуйте от него другие скрипты. Не придется писать одинаковый код.

Answer (score 0):

Можно поместить if в нужный метод и создать логическую переменную, которая будет включать/выключать все, что находится внутри.

Пример:

```
public bool a;

void Method()
{
    if(a == true)
    {
        //Содержимое метода
    }
}
```

Comment: С вопросе метод не void

Comment: @aepot А это как-то меняет смысл моего ответа?

Comment: Я понимаю ,что можно сделать так ,но это слишком варворски выглядит ,нет ли способа вообще не компилировать функцию ,но так ,что бы она не компилировалась у 1 отдельного объекта?

Comment: Понимаю звучит дико и глупо ,но я просто не хочу писать 3 скрипта )

Comment: Кстати, можно еще для надежности `if(a == true && a != false)`. :) Зачем bool сравнивать с bool, чтобы получить в итоге bool для выполнения условия? Ведь можно просто `if (a)`. Компилятор этот странный код все равно оптимизирует как надо, просто интересно. Вы же не пишете `myString.ToString()`. Или пишете? :)

Comment: ~Смешно-смешно.

Comment: @Аленя́ кстати, здесь есть такие, которые пишут `if(a == false)` вместо `if(!a)`. На полном серьезе, типа кому-то так легче читать код. А вот `== true` пока еще не видел. :)

Comment: Учту ваше замечание